# How does WordPress add line-breaks to the content?

Tags: php, wordpress

Currently I am working on a content migration from WordPress to another CMS.

I have used the default content export function of WordPress, which creates an XML file containing all content. This works fine, except for the fact that all `<br>`'s are missing.

So then I ran PHP's `nl2br` on the content, which works OK for some lines, but also adds `<br>` in places where it shouldn't be, like between a `<ul>` and a `<li>` element.

In the database the WordPress content doesn't contain the `<br>`'s, so the content export seems to be accurate for that matter.
However, in the final HTML output of the WordPress website, the HTML does contain `<br>`'s.
So I was wondering: how does WordPress add the `<br>`'s and how does it know where to and where not to add them?
Can anyone point out the spot where WordPress adds them?

**Content example in the database:**

```
<strong>Something:</strong> Something else
<strong>Another point:</strong> Lorem ipsum

<ul>
    <li><strong>Some text</strong></li>
    <li><strong>Some other text</strong></li>
</ul>
```

**My `nl2br` will result in:**

```
<strong>Something:</strong> Something else<br>
<strong>Another point:</strong> Lorem ipsum<br>
<br>
<ul><br>
    <li><strong>Some text</strong></li><br>
    <li><strong>Some other text</strong></li><br>
</ul><br>
```

**The output WordPress generates:**

```
<strong>Something:</strong> Something else<br />
<strong>Another point:</strong> Lorem ipsum<br />

<ul>
    <li><strong>Some text</strong></li>
    <li><strong>Some other text</strong></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That happens inside the filters WP applies to content before outputting it. The basic one used in most places would be `the_content`. You can explicitly execute filters on given pieces of content using https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/apply_filters/

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to look into that and get back to you about it. You may want to post this in an actual answer though, so that I can call it "the answer" if it actually is the answer to the question.

Comment: _“if it actually is the answer to the question”_ - I’m always a bit reluctant and rather wait for confirmation of that :-)

Comment: I now added the actual function as an answer (I found it in wp-includes/formatting.php). However: do you know whether it's possible to apply that function to the XML export?

Comment: Not sure; after all, the main purpose of that functionality is to export the _data_ as-is, not any visual representation of it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the actual code where WordPress adds the `<br>`'s (and it's not pretty...)

It's a lot of logic in `wp-includes/formatting.php::wpautop()`
I guess I'll copy that functionality to my import-script then.